# Toggle link HREF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu panel that is displayed via pure css - using `#nav` - its controlled by a simple button

```
<a id="nav-burger" href="#nav">
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
</a>
```

I'd like to toggle the href on click to display `#home` - can anyone advise how to do this?

I am using this format but my syntax is a bit messed up and there must be an easier way!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nav-burger').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
     $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href') == '#nav' ? '#nav' : '#home');
  });
});
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**
As a demo - In the code snippet below - whenever the link gos red the href should have the value of #home and visa versa fro blue (#nav)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nav-burger').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open').attr('href', function(_, currHref) {
    return currHref === '#nav' ? '#home' : '#nav';
  });
});
});
```

```css
a{color:blue}
a.open{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="nav-burger" href="#nav">
     
          hello
    
      </a>
```

Comment: I mean, not really... you don't have to use a ternary but it's.. ok here I guess. Seems fine. Does it not work?

Comment: `$(this).attr('href') == '#nav' ? '#home' : '#nav'`

Comment: Maybe just a bit more condensed and optimized : `var $this = $(this); $this.toggleClass('open').attr('href',$this.attr('href') == '#nav' ? '#home' : '#nav')`, but otherwise it's good

Comment: thanks for your help chaps - it works with @charlietfl answer but on 2nd click rather than first so out of sync..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`attr(attributeName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) and chain the methods

```
$('#nav-burger').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open').attr('href', function(_, currHref) {
    return currHref === '#nav' ? '#home' : '#nav';
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks @charlietfl - it works but not on first click - first click it does nothing - second it works fine - prob something simple but i'm scratching my head this friday afternoon!!

Comment: Create a really simple demo that reproduces issue

Comment: i tried to replicate above - but the url actually needs to change to show you wants happening - so its difficult to properly replicate - if i change the initial html to <a id="nav-burger" href="#home"> ie the opposite of what i want it to do initially it works fine... so its as though the code is switching the href before it fires..  very confusing

Comment: Yeah... that is right. It gets changed before event completes and event uses newer version...add a `setTimeout()` with next to no delay so event will complete first

Comment: technically as this is a simple animated panel open / close toggle - i guess it does no harm to switch the initial html state anyhow - in which case itw orks and thanks very much!